# what is the difference between SIP proxy and outbound proxy

Tags: sip

What is the difference between SIP Proxy server and Outbound proxy server.

I am using asterisk and I see two fields - proxy address and outbound proxy address.

Answer (score 0):

Outbound proxy server is the server your sip request will be sent to; its similar to default gateway we set in IP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to SIP

Proxy Server - Any server that proxies your request i.e. an entity between UAC and UAS, that forwards the request to UAS on your behalf.

Outbound Server - As earlier said by parag, its like default gateway. Any SIP request from you SIP client will go to this server. This is configured in your client. It can be used for policy enforcement.